# MapPartition in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am extremely new to Python and not very familiar with the syntax. I am looking at some sample implementation of the pyspark mappartitions method. To articulate the ask better, I have written the Java Equivalent of what I need.

```
JavaRDD<Row> modified =  auditSet.javaRDD().mapPartitions(new FlatMapFunction<Iterator<Row>, Row>() {

            public Iterator<Row> call(Iterator<Row> t) throws Exception {
                Iterable<Row> iterable = () -> t;
                return StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false).map(m -> enrich(m)).iterator();
            }
            private Row enrich(Row r) {
                //<code to enrich row r
                return RowFactory.create(/*new row from enriched row r*/);
            }

});
```

I have an rdd. I need to call the mappartitions on it. I am not sure how to pass/handle the iterator inside of python. Once the call reaches the method, I am looking to iterate each record and enrich it and return the result.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: will scala code work for you?

Comment: Thanks, but looking for Python implementation. I can do the scala part too.

Comment: Makes sense if the downvoting is explained. That way I can improve upon the next ask. Have I violated some rule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the right way, but this is what I have done. Open to comments and corrections.

```
auditSetDF.rdd.mapPartitions(lambda itr:mpImpl(itr,locationListBrdcast))

def mpImpl(itr,broadcastList):
        lst=broadcastList.value
        for x in itr:
                yield enrich(x,lst)
```

Comment: could you explain the reason for broadcast? In the Java version this was not present. What does broadcastList contain and how it is used?

Comment: The broadcast list is what I use inside my enrich() logic. I commented off the part in Java, I do have it though. I did not have to explicitly pass it since it had the right scope.